# Programming not sending verification code to given phone number

Tags: ios, swift, path

I am trying to figure out how to send a verification code to a user when signing up to verify their number. I am trying to follow online resources (code below), but it doesn't seem to work. When I put in a phone number as an 'xxxyyyzzzz' or 'xxx-yyy-zzzz' number (with a country code formatted just as the number, no '+') I get an error in my console that the phone number is not properly formatted. I'm not sure if this is the source of my issue, but as of now it seems the most probable. What confuses me about this is that online I am told that either of these formats will work. Any help? Code:

```
static let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Config", ofType: "plist")
static let config = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path!)
private static let baseURLString = config!["serverUrl"] as! String

@IBOutlet var countryCodeField: UITextField! = UITextField()
@IBOutlet var phoneNumberField: UITextField! = UITextField()

@IBAction func sendVerification(_ sender: Any) {
    if let phoneNumber = phoneNumberField.text,
        let countryCode = countryCodeField.text {
        SignUp2ViewController.sendVerificationCode(countryCode, phoneNumber)
    }
}

static func sendVerificationCode(_ countryCode: String, _ phoneNumber: String) {

    let parameters = [
        "via": "sms",
        "country_code": countryCode,
        "phone_number": phoneNumber
    ]

    let path = "start"
    let method = "POST"

    let urlPath = "\(baseURLString)/\(path)"
    var components = URLComponents(string: urlPath)!

    var queryItems = [URLQueryItem]()

    for (key, value) in parameters {
        let item = URLQueryItem(name: key, value: value)
        queryItems.append(item)
    }

    components.queryItems = queryItems

    let url = components.url!

    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = method

    let session: URLSession = {
        let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        return URLSession(configuration: config)
    }()

    let task = session.dataTask(with: request) {
        (data, response, error) in
        if let data = data {
            do {
                let jsonSerialized = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String : Any]

                print(jsonSerialized!)
            }  catch let error as NSError {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        } else if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling a POST but passing the values into the URL as if it's a GET. You should use the `httpBody` for POST.